# Optional field type doesn't conform protocol in Swift 3

Tags: swift

I have a class with 1 optional field and 1 non-optional field, both of them with Type **AnotherClass** and also conform ***CustomProtocol***:

```
protocol CustomProtocol {}

class CustomClass: CustomProtocol {

    var nonoptionalField: AnotherClass = AnotherClass()
    var optionalField: AnotherClass?

}

class AnotherClass: CustomProtocol {

}
```

The field **nonoptionalField** is type ***AnotherClass*** and conforms ***CustomProtocol***.

On the other hand, **optionalField** is actually ***Optional< AnotherClass>*** and therefore DOES NOT conform ***CustomProtocol***:

```
for field in Mirror(reflecting: CustomClass()).children {
    let fieldMirror = Mirror(reflecting: field.value)
    if fieldMirror.subjectType is CustomProtocol.Type {
        print("\(field.label!) is \(fieldMirror.subjectType) and conforms CustomProtocol")
    } else {
        print("\(field.label!) is \(fieldMirror.subjectType) and DOES NOT conform CustomProtocol")
    }
}
// nonoptionalField is AnotherClass and conforms CustomProtocol
// optionalField is Optional<AnotherClass> and DOES NOT conform CustomProtocol
```

How can I unwrap the Type (not the value) of **optionalField** property, so that I can associate it with its protocol ***CustomProtocol***?

In other words, how can I get the wrapped Type ***AnotherClass*** from ***Optional< AnotherClass>*** Type?

**LIMITATION:**

I really have to use Swift reflection through Mirror and unfortunately the property **.subjectType** doesn't allow to unwrap the optional wrapped Type of ***Optional< AnotherClass>*** so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not believe there's a simple way to do this, given that we currently cannot talk in terms of generic types without their placeholders – therefore we cannot simply cast to `Optional.Type`.

Nor can we cast to `Optional<Any>.Type`, because the compiler doesn't provide the same kinds of automatic conversions for metatype values that it provides for instances (e.g An `Optional<Int>` is convertible to an `Optional<Any>`, but an `Optional<Int>.Type` is not convertible to a `Optional<Any>.Type`).

However one solution, albeit a somewhat hacky one, would be to define a 'dummy protocol' to represent an 'any `Optional` instance', regardless of the `Wrapped` type. We can then have this protocol define a `wrappedType` requirement in order to get the `Wrapped` metatype value for the given `Optional` type.

For example:

```
protocol OptionalProtocol {
  // the metatype value for the wrapped type.
  static var wrappedType: Any.Type { get }
}

extension Optional : OptionalProtocol {
  static var wrappedType: Any.Type { return Wrapped.self }
}
```

Now if `fieldMirror.subjectType` is an `Optional<Wrapped>.Type`, we can cast it to `OptionalProtocol.Type`, and from there get the `wrappedType` metatype value. This then lets us check for `CustomProtocol` conformance.

```
for field in Mirror(reflecting: CustomClass()).children {
  let fieldMirror = Mirror(reflecting: field.value)

  // if fieldMirror.subjectType returns an optional metatype value
  // (i.e an Optional<Wrapped>.Type), we can cast to OptionalProtocol.Type,
  // and then get the Wrapped type, otherwise default to fieldMirror.subjectType
  let wrappedType = (fieldMirror.subjectType as? OptionalProtocol.Type)?.wrappedType
    ?? fieldMirror.subjectType

  // check for CustomProtocol conformance.
  if wrappedType is CustomProtocol.Type {
    print("\(field.label!) is \(fieldMirror.subjectType) and conforms CustomProtocol")
  } else {
    print("\(field.label!) is \(fieldMirror.subjectType) and DOES NOT conform CustomProtocol")
  }
}

// nonoptionalField is AnotherClass and conforms CustomProtocol
// optionalField is Optional<AnotherClass> and conforms CustomProtocol
```

This only deals with a single level of optional nesting, but could easily be adapted to apply to an arbitrary optional nesting level through simply repeatedly attempting to cast the resultant metatype value to `OptionalProtocol.Type` and getting the `wrappedType`, and then checking for `CustomProtocol` conformance.

```
class CustomClass : CustomProtocol {
    var nonoptionalField: AnotherClass = AnotherClass()
    var optionalField: AnotherClass??
    var str: String = ""
}

/// If `type` is an `Optional<T>` metatype, returns the metatype for `T`
/// (repeating the unwrapping if `T` is an `Optional`), along with the number of
/// times an unwrap was performed. Otherwise just `type` will be returned.
func seeThroughOptionalType(
  _ type: Any.Type
) -> (wrappedType: Any.Type, layerCount: Int) {

  var type = type
  var layerCount = 0

  while let optionalType = type as? OptionalProtocol.Type {
    type = optionalType.wrappedType
    layerCount += 1
  }
  return (type, layerCount)
}

for field in Mirror(reflecting: CustomClass()).children {

  let fieldMirror = Mirror(reflecting: field.value)
  let (wrappedType, _) = seeThroughOptionalType(fieldMirror.subjectType)

  if wrappedType is CustomProtocol.Type {
    print("\(field.label!) is \(fieldMirror.subjectType) and conforms CustomProtocol")
  } else {
    print("\(field.label!) is \(fieldMirror.subjectType) and DOES NOT conform CustomProtocol")
  }
}
// nonoptionalField is AnotherClass and conforms CustomProtocol
// optionalField is Optional<Optional<AnotherClass>> and conforms CustomProtocol
// str is String and DOES NOT conform CustomProtocol
```

Comment: I'm corrected as wrong! I was fiddling around with the very same `Optional` extension (even the same varname :D), but my train of thought never left the hierarchical layer of `Optional`, as it didn't hit me you could add a custom base protocol to `Optional` that can act as our castable type. Nice! (And hacky! :)

Comment: @dfri Thanks – I've found 'dummy protocols' seem to be the solution to quite a few type problems in Swift, usually concerning generic types where you just want to know whether it's a given generic type, but don't care about the placeholder. Although hopefully, future versions of Swift will actually introduce language features to allow us to do away with these somewhat hacky workarounds :) Actually a prime example of this is concrete-same type requirements for extensions, which used to have to be solved with dummy protocols – but now no longer :D

Comment: Thanks @Hamish, very clever and simple solution and it works like a charm as well!

Comment: @Hamish How do you actually cast the optional field to the protocol type, rather than just checking whether it conforms to it?

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question, but after fiddling around with it for a while, I previously believed (and was corrected wrong) that this could not be solved using native Swift, which, however, has been shown possibly by [@Hamish:s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42753986/4573247).

---

#### The goal

We want access, conditionally at runtime, the `Wrapped` type (`Optional<Wrapped>`) of an instance wrapped in `Any`, without actually knowing `Wrapped`, only knowing that `Wrapped` possibly conforms to some protocol; in your example `CustomProtocol`.

### The (not insurmountable) obstacles

There are a few obstacles hindering us in reaching a solution to this introspection problem, namely to test, at runtime, whether an instance of `Optional<Wrapped>` wrapped, in itself, in an instance of `Any`, holds a type `Wrapped` that conforms to a given protocol (where `Wrapped` is not known). Specifically, hindering us from a general solution that is viable *even for the case where the value being introspected upon happens to be `Optional<Wrapped>.none`*.

The first problem, as already noted in your question, is that optionals wrapped in `Any` instances are not covariant (optionals themselves are covariant, but that is in special case present also for e.g. some collections, whereas for custom wrapping types the default behaviour of non-covariance holds). Hence, we cannot successfully test conformance of the type wrapped in `Any` at its optional level, vs `Optional<MyProtocol>`, even if `Wrapped` itself conforms to `MyProtocol`.

```
protocol Dummy {}
extension Int : Dummy {}

let foo: Int? = nil
let bar = foo as Any

if type(of: bar) is Optional<Int>.Type {
    // OK, we enter here, but here we've assumed that we actually
    // know the type of 'Wrapped' (Int) at compile time!
}

if type(of: bar) is Optional<Dummy>.Type {
    // fails to enter as optionals wrapped in 'Any' are not covariant ...
}
```

The second problem is somewhat overlapping: we may not cast an `Any` instance containing an optional directly to the optional type, or (by noncovariance) to an optional type of a protocol to which the wrapped type conforms. E.g.:

```
let foo: Int? = 1
let bar = foo as Any
let baz = bar as? Optional<Int>
// error: cannot downcast from 'Any' to a more optional type 'Optional<Int>'
let dummy = bar as? Optional<Dummy>
// error: cannot downcast from 'Any' to a more optional type 'Optional<Dummy>'
```

Now, we can circumvent this using a value-binding pattern:

```
protocol Dummy {}
extension Int : Dummy {}

let foo: Int? = 1
let bar = foo as Any
if case Optional<Any>.some(let baz) = bar {
    // ok, this is great, 'baz' is now a concrete 'Wrapped' instance,
    // in turn wrapped in 'Any': but fo this case, we can  test if 
    // 'baz' conforms to dummy!
    print(baz)          // 1
    print(baz is Dummy) // true <--- this would be the OP's end goal
}

// ... but what if 'bar' is wrapping Optional<Int>.none ?
```

But this is only a workaround that helps in case `foo` above is non-`nil`, whereas if `foo` is `nil`, we have no binded instance upon which we may perform type & protocol conformance analysis.

```
protocol Dummy {}
extension Int : Dummy {}

let foo: Int? = nil
let bar = foo as Any
if case Optional<Any>.none = bar {
    // ok, so we know that bar indeed wraps an optional,
    // and that this optional happens to be 'nil', but
    // we have no way of telling the compiler to work further
    // with the actual 'Wrapped' type, as we have no concrete
    // 'Wrapped' value to bind to an instance.
}
```

I'm been playing around with a few different approaches, but in the end I come back to the issue that for an optional `nil`-valued instance wrapped in `Any`, accessing `Wrapped` (without knowing it: e.g. as a metatype) seems non-possible. As shown in [@Hamish:s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42753986/4573247), however, this is indeed not insurmountable, and can be solved by adding an additional protocol layer *above* `Optional`.

I'll leave my not-quite-the-finish-line attempts above, however, as the techniques and discussion may be instructive for readers of this thread, even if they didn't manage to solve the problem.

Comment: It's kind of annoying how the compiler rejects the conditional cast from `Any` to `Optional` – the very nature of `Any` surely means that, well, it could be *anything*, including an `Optional` (I recall the behaviour used to work, not quite sure when they changed it). Although I guess it makes sense considering Obj-C interop which deals a lot with `Any` and `Any?`, and probably helps to avoid weird behaviours with `Any` and `Optional` mixing – I can't help but feel it should be a warning rather than an error though...

Comment: @Hamish yes I also recall that it used to be possible. Possible the already present [optional nestedness](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Optional.swift#L719) in the ObjC bridge could be a reason for this "regression", in case it was intentional. I also feel somewhat split over the fact that a `.none` instance wrapped in an `Any` instance is so difficult to distract `Wrapped` type info from. Since the case has nothing to do with `Wrapped`, I guess this is to be expected, but since optionals are their own very special types, I wouldn't protest if this was easier:)