# Checking if a metatype is an Array with an Element type of kind MyProtocol

Tags: arrays, swift, generics

I need do different things for different classes. For example I've created the protocols

```
protocol ResponseProtocol {
    associatedtype ResponseType: Any
}

protocol MappableProtocol {
    init(map: String)
}
```

and I'm adding my data class `MyDto`

```
class MyDto: MappableProtocol {
    required init(map: String) { }
}
```

and 3 different response classes

```
class A1: ResponseProtocol {
    typealias ResponseType = String
}

class A2: ResponseProtocol {
    typealias ResponseType = MyDto
}

class A3: ResponseProtocol {
    typealias ResponseType = [MyDto]
}
```

now I need do different things depending on `ResponseType`.

I tried this code, but I'm running into problems with `Array`s

```
class API {

    func test<T: ResponseProtocol>(a: T) -> String {

        if T.ResponseType.self is String.Type {
            return "String"
        }
        if T.ResponseType.self is MappableProtocol.Type {
            return "MappableProtocol"
        }


        if T.ResponseType.self is [Any].Type {
            return "Array<Any>" // Why is this false?
        }
        if T.ResponseType.self is [MappableProtocol].Type {
            return "Array<MappableProtocol>" //Why is this false?
        }
        if T.ResponseType.self is [MyDto].Type {
            return "Array<MyDto>" // Why is only this true?
        }
        return "notFound"
    }

}
let api = API()
let t1 = api.test(a: A1())
let t2 = api.test(a: A2())
let t3 = api.test(a: A3())
```

In my playground console, for array `A3`, I see `Array<MyDto>`, but I expected the first return for array like `Array<Any>`.

How can I check for an `Array` where the `Element` is of kind `MappableProtocol`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that while *instances* of `[MyDto]` can be freely converted to `[MappableProtocol]` and `[Any]`, these are really just magical conversions that the compiler does behind the scenes (see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37188580/2976878) for more information).

The same conversions don't exist for metatype values, which is why Swift says that a `[MyDto].Type` is not a `[MappableProtocol].Type` nor a `[Any].Type` – they are unrelated metatype types.

Likely the simplest solution in your case would just be to forget working with metatypes, and instead just declare different *overloads* of `test(a:)` to handle different `ResponseType` types.

```
// 'default' overload of test(a:)
func test<T : ResponseProtocol>(a: T) -> String {
    return "notFound"
}

func test<T : ResponseProtocol>(a: T) -> String where T.ResponseType == String {
    return "String"
}

func test<T : ResponseProtocol>(a: T) -> String where T.ResponseType : MappableProtocol {
    return "MappableProtocol"
}

func test<T : ResponseProtocol>(a: T) -> String where T.ResponseType == [MyDto] {
    return "Array<MDto>"
}

// overload of test(a:) that accepts a type that conforms to ResponseProtocol, where the
// ResponseType is an Array with arbitrary Element type.
func test<T : ResponseProtocol, ResponseTypeElement : MappableProtocol>(a: T) -> String
    where T.ResponseType == [ResponseTypeElement]
{
    return "Array<MappableProtocol>"
}

print(test(a: A1())) // String
print(test(a: A2())) // MappableProtocol
print(test(a: A3())) // Array<MyDto>

// A MappableProtocol with a ResponseType that conforms to MappableProtocol,
// but isn't MyDto.
class Foo : MappableProtocol { required init(map: String) { } }
class A4  : ResponseProtocol { typealias ResponseType = [Foo] }

print(test(a: A4())) // Array<MappableProtocol>
```

<sup>(I removed your `API` class just to simplify things)</sup>

The compiler will simply resolve which overload to call at compile time, rather than having the runtime jump through lots of type-casting hoops.

---

If you *insist* on working with metatype values, one possible solution is to define a *dummy protocol* for `Array` to conform to (see for example [this similar Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42752242/2976878)), which we can then cast the metatype values to. We can then declare an `elementType` static requirement in order to extract the `Array`'s `Element.self` metatype value, which we can then inspect the type of in order to determine what the array is convertible to.

For example, if we define and conform `Array` to `_ArrayProtocol`:

```
protocol _ArrayProtocol {
    static var elementType: Any.Type { get }
}

extension Array : _ArrayProtocol {
    static var elementType: Any.Type {
        return Element.self
    }
}
```

We can now use `test(a:)` like so:

```
func test<T : ResponseProtocol>(a: T) -> String {

    if T.ResponseType.self is String.Type {
        return "String"
    }

    if T.ResponseType.self is MappableProtocol.Type {
        return "MappableProtocol"
    }

    // attempt to cast the T.ResponseType.self metatype value to the existential metatype
    // type _ArrayProtocol.Type (i.e a type that conforms to _ArrayProtocol),
    // in this case, that's only ever Array.
    if let responseType = T.ResponseType.self as? _ArrayProtocol.Type {

        // switch on the element type, attempting to cast to different metatype types.
        switch responseType.elementType {
        case is MyDto.Type:
            return "Array<MyDto>"
        case is MappableProtocol.Type:
            return "Array<MappableProtocol>"
        default:
            return "Array<Any>"
        }
    }

    return "notFound"
}

print(test(a: A1())) // String
print(test(a: A2())) // MappableProtocol
print(test(a: A3())) // Array<MyDto>
print(test(a: A4())) // Array<MappableProtocol>
```

Comment: Can you help me with `Dictionary`. I tied this code, by your example    `func sortDescriptor<T: Dictionary<String, ValueElement>, ValueElement: Any>(a: T) -> String
    where T.Element.value: ValueElement
{
    return "Dictionary <Any>"
}`. But this not worked

Comment: @EvGeniyIlyin `Dictionary<String, ValueElement>` is neither a class nor a protocol, so you cannot use it as a generic constraint. It's unclear exactly what you meant for `ValueElement` to be in this context – is it an existing protocol? If so, you probably meant `func sortDescriptor<Value>(a: [String : Value]) -> String where Value : ValueElement`. Remember: use generic placeholders to describe the type that *varies* – in this case `Dictionary<String, ...>` is constant, so it's defined as the parameter type, rather than in a generic placeholder.

Comment: If you just meant "a dictionary with a `String` key, but any type of value" – you meant to say `func sortDescriptor<Value>(a: [String : Value]) -> String`.

Comment: @EvGeniyIlyin But really, if you have a new problem – you should [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) (after, of course, first doing some research) rather than asking it as a follow-up question in the comments.