# How can you check if a type is Optional in Swift?

Tags: swift, option-type

How can you check if a type is Optional in Swift?

Say I have a variable of type PartialKeyPath where:

```
struct Foo {
    let bar: String
    let baz: String?
}

typealias Property<Root> = (key: PartialKeyPath<Root>, value: Any?)
typealias Properties<Root> = [Property<Root>]
```

Now say I iterate thru an instance of Properties:

```
properties.forEach { prop in
    let valueType1 = type(of: prop.key).valueType
    let valueType2 = type(of: value)

    ...
```

How can I check here whether valueType1 is `Optional<valueType2>`, or whether it is Optional of any other flavor for that matter?

So far the only way I’ve found is really ugly...

Comment: What for is `struct Foo`?

Comment: Also, your code will not even compile.`PartialKeyPath<Root>` class has no `valueType` instance variable.

Comment: @kelin It’s a class variable bro. `static var valueType: Any.Type { get }` is on all KeyPath types...

Comment: @kelin Also, `struct Foo` is for where the keyPaths will point.

Comment: yes bro it is `static`. I was pointing on that. I'm glad that you found it and edited the question.

Comment: You could use a similar approach to https://stackoverflow.com/q/42752242/2976878, however there's almost certainly a better way to do whatever you're trying to do here. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a hacky but working solution:

```
func isOptional(_ type: Any.Type) -> Bool {
    let typeName = String(describing: type)
    return typeName.hasPrefix("Optional<")
}
```

Test:

```
let t1 = Int?.self
let t2 = Bool.self

print(isOptional(t1))
// true

print(isOptional(t2))
// false
```

Comment: Yeah that’s the ugly solution I did. Except I also checked to see if it had the name of the type as well. Was hoping there was a better solution sigh

Comment: This will fail if the type has name that begins with "Optional", such as `Optionality`

Comment: Update: added `<` so now this check will not fail for types starting with Optional. @CodeDifferent, thank you for attention!

Answer (score 11):

Using a similar approach to [Optional field type doesn't conform protocol in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42752242/2976878), you could define a 'dummy protocol' for `Optional` and use this to get the wrapped metatype:

```
protocol OptionalProtocol {
  // the metatype value for the wrapped type.
  static var wrappedType: Any.Type { get }
}

extension Optional : OptionalProtocol {
  static var wrappedType: Any.Type { return Wrapped.self }
}
```

If you just want to know a type is an optional:

```
func isOptionalType(_ type: Any.Type) -> Bool {
  return type is OptionalProtocol.Type
}

print(isOptionalType(String.self)) // false
print(isOptionalType(String?.self)) // true
```

If you want to check if one metatype is the 'optional version' of another metatype:

```
struct Foo {
  let bar: String
  let baz: String?
}

struct Property<Root> {
  var key: PartialKeyPath<Root>
  var value: Any
}

let properties = [Property(key: \Foo.baz, value: "hello")]

/// Attempt to get the `Wrapped` metatype from a metatype of an
/// `Optional<Wrapped>`. If not an `Optional`, will return `nil`.
func wrappedTypeFromOptionalType(_ type: Any.Type) -> Any.Type? {
  return (type as? OptionalProtocol.Type)?.wrappedType
}

for property in properties {
  let valueType1 = type(of: property.key).valueType
  let valueType2 = type(of: property.value)

  if wrappedTypeFromOptionalType(valueType1) == valueType2 {
    print("\(valueType1) == Optional<\(valueType2)>")
  }
}

// Optional<String> == Optional<String>
```

However there's almost certainly a better way to do whatever you're trying to do here with the key paths.

Comment: The only better ways involve mods to the Swift compiler!

Comment: @CommaToast If/when Swift ever supports talking about generic types without their placeholders, then it’d be as simple as `type is Optional.Type` – until then, I believe this is the next best alternative.

Comment: This should be the selected answer!

Answer (score 3):

could you use a mirror reflecting Any and check displayStyle is optional?.

```
func isOptional(any:Any) -> Bool {

  let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: any)
  if mirror.displayStyle == .Optional {
      return true
  } else {
      return false
  }

}
```

More on mirror display style:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mirror.displaystyle

Comment: Why not just `return mirror.displayStyle == .Optional`?

Comment: That works too, but because in either case s/he may want to run some operation. if just checking if optional or not you can just refer to self in an extension and return mirror.displayStyle == .Optional.

Comment: That helps me see if it’s optional, but not if it’s Optional<valueType2>...

Comment: @Ercell0 check out the way I got your idea to work... see the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

A tweak of @kelin’s answer:

```
postfix operator ...?!
postfix func ...?!<T>(_ instance: T) -> Bool {
    let subject = "\(Mirror(reflecting: instance).subjectType)"
    return !subject.hasPrefix("Optional") 
}
```

And in the vein of @Ercell0’s answer is this superior method:

```
func isOptional<T>(_ instance: T) -> Bool {
    guard let displayStyle = Mirror(reflecting: instance).displayStyle 
        else { return false }
    return displayStyle == .optional
}
```

Comment: @kelin check it out