# Compare Swift Any.Type with respect of inheritance

Tags: swift

I'm trying to compare two `Any.Type`.
What I want to check is whether some type is equal **OR** inherits from that type.

Eg. `UIView` type is `UIView.Type` but it also inherits from `NSObject.Type`.
I'm having problems to check the second one.
Is it possible with Swift?

Exmaple:

```
class Object: NSObject {
    var name: String = "aloha"
}

class Other {
    var obj: Object?
}


let key = \Other.obj
let keyType = type(of: key)

keyType.valueType == Object?.self // true
keyType.valueType == NSObject.self // false - how can I make it true?
```

## **Edit 1:**

My final goal is to have a generic VC to edit any (CoreData) object. I want to display different cells based on var's types.
I find a different way for achieving what I described above (I hope - the better way).
I'm still strugling though with one issue here. Although I can finally find out object's type, I want to check if that type conforms to my protocol, and if yes - call its methods.
Sample code will probably explain it better:

```
protocol MyProtocol: class {
    static func someIdentifier() -> String
}

class Object: NSObject, MyProtocol {
    var name: String = "aloha"

    static func someIdentifier() -> String {
        return "This is it!"
    }
}

class Other: NSObject {
    var obj: Object?

}


let key = \Other.obj
let keyType = type(of: key)

let other = Other()
let value: Any? = other[keyPath: key]

if let object = value as? NSObject? {
    if let protocolObject = object as? MyProtocol {
        print("Yey!") // Can't get here :< What should I do to be able to call methods of MyProtocol?
        // protocolObject.myIdentifier() // :< How?
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your actual code. The code you have posted doesn't even compile.

Comment: Looks like it should be `let key = \Other.obj`.

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve here? There's almost certainly a better solution that doesn't involve comparing metatypes. That being said, you'd want to say `is NSObject.Type` instead of `== NSObject.self`, though that won't work directly with `keyType.valueType`, as its a metatype of an optional, so you'll need to use something like the `wrappedTypeFromOptionalType(_:)` function from https://stackoverflow.com/a/47860339/2976878, or `seeThroughOptionalType(_:)` function from https://stackoverflow.com/a/42753986/2976878. But as I said, you probably don't need this.

Comment: I've edited a question description with more details :)

Answer (score 0):

You ***Can't get here*** because `value` aka `obj` is `nil`.

Please look at this. I changed `someIdentifier()` to an instance method and assigned an `Object` instance to `obj`. Further  I removed the unnecessary type annotation `let value: Any?` because a type cast from `Object` to `Any` makes it worse and consolidated the optional down cast `if let object = value as NSObject?` by removing the second question mark.

```
protocol MyProtocol: class {
    func someIdentifier() -> String
}

class Object: NSObject, MyProtocol {
    var name: String = "aloha"

    func someIdentifier() -> String {
        return "This is it!"
    }
}

class Other: NSObject {
    var obj: Object?
}


let key = \Other.obj
let keyType = type(of: key)

let other = Other()
other.obj = Object()
let value = other[keyPath: key]

if let object = value as NSObject? {
    if let protocolObject = object as? MyProtocol {
        print(protocolObject.someIdentifier()) // This is it!
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @vadian but I deliberetaly was using `Static` method in the protocol because `obj` can be `nil` in many cases and I still want to call that protocol method on its type.

Comment: You cannot call a static function on the protocol type.

Comment: I can call though `Object.someIdentifier()`. How it’s workig then?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. But then `protocolObject` is obsolete and you could check `if object is MyProtocol { ...`