# Swift build generic type at runtime

Tags: swift, generics, reflection, runtime

Swift 5.1
Suppose I'm deserializing some data.  I'm interested in reconstructing the exact same types as were serialized, but some may involve generics.  Consider the following example case.

```
let layers = 4
let value: Int64 = 17

var output: Any

???SOMETHING???

print("\(type(of: output))") // "Optional<Optional<Optional<Optional<Int64>>>>"
```

Is there a way to get an `output` with a runtime type of `Optional<...Optional<Int64>...>`, where the number of nested layers of `Optional` is equal to `layers`?  (And doesn't rely on e.g. hard-coded case statements full of classes.)  Perhaps reflection, some type initializers I don't know about, maybe some black magic use of pointers or `object_setClass` or something?

I would also accept strong evidence that it is fundamentally impossible in Swift, such as documentation stating that every specification of a generic class used in a program is generated individually at compiletime, and therefore you cannot newly specify a generic class at runtime.  ...Though even in that case, it might still be possible, considering things like Java's `ClassLoader`s.

Comment: All Swift types need to be known at compiler time. Also, why are you having nested Optional types? If you have that - especially with more than 2 layers, that usually signals bad design. Your question in its current form cannot be properly answered. Please update it with the actual problem you are trying to solve instead of a description obscured to such a high level that it isn't possible to answer in a practical fashion.

Comment: As I alluded in the first sentence, I'm deserializing data.  I'm not in control of the types they pass me, and nested optionals are a valid Swift type.  I would therefore like to support them, as exactly as possible.

Comment: Deserialising data doesn't really mean anything. What format is your data stored in? How dynamic is that data? So you always know `layers` and the `type` of `value`, but you only gather these pieces of information in runtime?

Comment: @DávidPásztor The true criteria are that I'm writing both the serialization and deserialization code, which converts between Swift objects and [UInt8]s. The serialization code is given a single Swift object at a time, with a runtime type comprised of any legal combination of fundamental Swift classes/structures (e.g. String, the integer types, the floating point types, Bool, arrays, dictionaries, tuples, and Optionals) as well as specific classes not listed here and handled individually, and returns a [UInt8] containing any data the deserialization code needs that CAN be stored as a [UInt8].

Comment: @DávidPásztor The deserialization code must accept a [UInt8], and return an object of exactly the same runtime type as the object given to the serialization code. I decline to include the specs for correctness of value in my question (as opposed to correctness of type), in part because I've already done most of that (sans identical typing) and the remainder is straightforward.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Now, most of the above detail seemed unnecessary for the core question, and given that Jonathan appears to have correctly understood my intent and made a few reasonable forays into solving the problem, I'm inclined to keep my previous opinion. However, if you'd rather solve my full problem and save me a bunch of work, then by all means, I would welcome such a complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
let layers = 100
let value: Int64 = 17
var output: Any = value

for _ in 1...layers {
    output = Optional(output)
}

print(output)
```

However, printing the type of *output* is `Optional<Any>`
Which is sad.

---

I've run into more errors, too

```
// Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Optional<Any>' (0x7fff91c591e8) to 'Any.Type' (0x7fff91c59288).
// Cannot downcast from 'Any' to a more optional type 'Optional<_>'
```

---

I did find this answer which is pretty good.
But it doesn't really return the wrapped type, it just checks if its optional.
Some of the answers are really good
[How can you check if a type is Optional in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47690210/how-can-you-check-if-a-type-is-optional-in-swift)

---

Here's a few attempts I made
I was trying to count how many nested Optionals something has
(This didn't work)

```
protocol OptionalProtocol { static var wrappedType: Any.Type { get } }
extension Optional : OptionalProtocol {
    static var wrappedType: Any.Type { return Wrapped.self }
    // static var wrapped: Any { return  }
}
func wrappedTypeFromOptionalType(_ type: Any.Type) -> Any.Type? {
  return (type as? OptionalProtocol.Type)?.wrappedType
}
```

```
var aaa: Any.Type? = wrappedTypeFromOptionalType(type(of: output))

while let aa = wrappedTypeFromOptionalType(type(of: aaa!)) {
    nested += 1
    aaa = aa
}
```

neither did this

```
while let aa = wrappedTypeFromOptionalType(type(of: aaa!)) {
    nested += 1
    aaa = aa
}
```

Comment: So your answer simply doesn't solve OP's problem, but rather confirms that you also ran into the issue and couldn't find a solution? If that's the case, this should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Well, to be fair, this wouldn't really fit in a comment, and it at least contains some elements that could be part of a true solution.