# swift type(of:) - show nonoptional type of optional

Tags: swift

For example, we have `var check: Int?` and we want to `print(String(describing: type(of: check)))`. We get in console `Optional<Int>`
How to get just `Int`?

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/42753986/2976878

Comment: Unwrap `check`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unwrap the Optional with the `!` operator:

```
 print(String(describing: type(of: check!)))
```

Comment: That works. Strange, I think I've tried that and got a run-time error. Sorry for this question.

Comment: Wrapped inside `type()` , `check!` is not evaluated, so you will not get a runtime error if `check` is nil- but sure, elsewhere you would get a runtime error when  `check`  is nil

Comment: I regard the force unwrapping without crashing within `type(of:)` [as a bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1327) (same as its predecessor `.dynamicType`), because really it should have the semantics of a function call (even though the compiler treats it as a special expression). Note btw that if `check` is typed as a class, or is a `let`, the force unwrap *can* crash.

Comment: @Hamish, i had 'let' ... Now everything is ok, thanks

Comment: @Anton Note that this bug [is now fixed](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/14410) – `type(of: check!)` *will* now correctly crash if `check` is `nil`. All things going well, the fix will make it into the release of Swift 4.2, so make sure you're not relying on it for when that comes around.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same issue. If, at runtime, `check` is not `nil`, you can simply unwrap it and do `type(of:)`, like:

```
if let unwrappedCheck = check {
    print(type(of: unwrappedCheck) // "Int"
}
```

But, what if check is `nil` at runtime and you want `type(of: check)` to give you `Int` and NOT `Optional<Int>`? The verified answer is incorrect because it will throw an exception at runtime. I think that was a bug — you can't force unwrap and do `type(of:)` if the thing you unwrap (`check`) is nil.

Since you know statically that `check` is of type `Int?`, this will be easy. You just need a way to expose the wrapped type of the Optional. Refer to the [official declaration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional) of `Optional`:

```
@frozen enum Optional<Wrapped>
```

> The Optional type is an enumeration with two cases. Optional.none is equivalent to the nil literal. Optional.some(Wrapped) stores a wrapped value.

Since Optional is technically an enum, you can use a short extension to forward the type of `Wrapped`.

```
extension Optional {
  typealias Wrapped = Wrapped
}
```

You can then use it as such:

```
let check: Int? = nil
let wrappedType = type(of: check).Wrapped
print(wrappedType) // "Int"
```

Answer (score -1):

> we can do in swift 5.x below solution.

```
enum Optional<Wrapped> {
    case none
    case some(Wrapped)
}

extension Optional {
    typealias Wrapped = Wrapped
}

var x: Optional<Int> = .some(10)
print(type(of: x).Wrapped) // It will print Int

x = .none
print(type(of: x).Wrapped) // It will print Int
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).